# Finding the number of solutions of 2 SAT

Tags: algorithm

I want an algorithm to know whether there exists more than one solution for 2-satisfiability problem say for 1000 literals assuming it is satisfiable. Please explain.

Comment: No not a homework assignment. A problem on online judge based on 2-SAT. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: could you give an example input?

Comment: Like (a+b)(!a+b) has 2 solutions (1,1) & (0,1). So how to check that more than one solution exists? Satisfiability just finds one of these solution randomly.

Comment: @qwery: Which online judge? I'm interested.

Comment: @qwery: in the above example after finding solution (1,1) you add blocking clause not (a and b), which in CNF looks like not a OR not b, run sat-solver again, and it won't return that solution again.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability):

> Feder (1994) describes an algorithm
>   for efficiently listing all solutions
>   to a given 2-satisfiability instance,
>   and for solving several related
>   problems.[14] Algorithms are also
>   known for counting the number of
>   solutions, more quickly than it would
>   be possible to list all solutions,[15]
>   and for finding pairs of solutions
>   that differ as greatly as
>   possible.[16]

Especially

> Dahllöf, Vilhelm; Jonsson, Peter;
>   Wahlström, Magnus (2005), "Counting
>   models for 2SAT and 3SAT formulae",
>   Theoretical Computer Science 332
>   (1–3): 265–291,
>   doi:10.1016/j.tcs.2004.10.037 ; Fürer,
>   Martin; Kasiviswanathan, Shiva Prasad
>   (2007), "Algorithms for counting 2-SAT
>   solutions and colorings with
>   applications", Algorithmic Aspects in
>   Information and Management, Lecture
>   Notes in Computer Science, 4508,
>   Springer-Verlag, pp. 47–57,
>   doi:10.1007/978-3-540-72870-2.

seems to be what you want.

---

Here's a diploma theses on this subject. It's quite lengthy, so it should be easier to follow: http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arazen/publications/2sat.pdf

And another one including Pseudo-Code: http://www.engineeringletters.com/issues_v15/issue_2/EL_15_2_12.pdf.

But since this problem is a non-trivial mathematical problem, you have to live with math in this case.

Comment: If you know the algorithm, can you explain me in a simpler language. These papers give algorithm in a very formal way.

Answer (score 4):

The OP wants to know if there is more than one solution.  First 2SAT is much easier: you make a directed labeled graph: each node corresponds to a literal (a variable or it's negation), and every clause of the form a OR b gives you a directed edge from (not a) to b and (not b) to a.  There is a satisfying assignment if and only if there is no path from a to (not a) for any literal a.  There is actually a linear time algorithm to determine this due to Aspvall, Plass and Tarjan (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component for references).  If the graph passes this test, you get a solution by choosing a source node in the graph, and finding all the implications (all paths).  Some of them will make some other nodes vanish (if a node is a, choosing it corresponds to making that literal true, so that the node (not a) is now removed).  Keep doing this until there's no more source nodes.  If there is another solution, then it must have one of the literals in the solution you've just found, negated.  So try each one in turn.  This gives a quadratic algorithm.  I would guess that there's probably a better one out there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by the statement of the problem and the title of your question.

If "to know whether there exists more than one solution" is really the only thing you need, listing all solutions is surely an overkill!
Find the first solution, say "A AND NOT B" and add a 'blocking clause', that is a guard, that turns a SAT-solver away from that solution.

In the mentioned example, such a constraint is "NOT (A AND NOT B)". Bring it to CNF and be happy :-)

Comment: Can u elaborate what do you mean by "blocking cause that is a guard.."?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just want to know whether there exists more than one solution or not? I dont want to enumerate all solution.

Comment: qwery: what madh is suggesting is to run your sat solver, find the first solution, then add a clause that explicitly filters out that solution and run the sat solver again. if you find a second solution, your problem has more than one.

Comment: Does blocking means removing the old clause and adding new guard clause OR retaining both? I suppose that we should remove the old clause. And say I have 1000 clauses, first thing is which clause should I block?(just randomly?). Even if I block a cause, it means that I want a solution which should complement the value of 2 literals invloved in the clause that I am guarding,but it may happen that a alternate solution exists with the same value for these two literals,but other literals changed OR a solution with just one of these literals changed,others remaining same(and no other solution)

Comment: CNF = Chomsky Normal Form or Chuck Norris Facts? :)

Comment: An example of a blocking clause is on
page 9 of this paper http://yury.chebiryak.name/SAT2009_Finding_LIC.pdf

Answer (score -3):

Counting of 2-SAT solutions is hard problem (maybe even NP-complete), because could be over than polynomial solutions. So in polynomial time we can't list all solutions.
I can't find fast algorithm by myself, so now I'm looking in network. 
But if fast algorithm exists than we can break RSA in polynomial time.